# Conditional Routing in React based on API calls

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I'm trying to create a React web app with multiple pages and connecting it to Flask to fetch data using the fetch API. Here is what I want to achieve:

If the user submits a Form, React does a POST request to the Flask API which returns a JSON object, which is received by React and I render the `predict` route. This is handled using the `Forms.jsx` component, which has the following code:

```
const Form = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const movie_submit = {title};
    console.log(movie_submit);

    fetch('/predict', {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(movie_submit)
    }).then(() => {
      (navigate("/predict"));
    })

  }
  return (
    <div className='form_container'>

        <form className='form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input type='text' placeholder='Movie Name' autoFocus 
          autoComplete='off' value={title} onChange={(e)=>setTitle(e.target.value)}/>
          <button className='button'>Recommend!</button>
        </form>
    </div>

  )
}

export default Form
```

Now I want to perform a GET request to the Flask API to get what should be put into the Predict.js page (/predict route), and the show it.

`Predict.js` is as:

```
const Predict = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/predict').then(response => 
      response.json().then(data => 
        {
        setMovies(Object.values(data));
    }))
    
  }, []);
  const movie_name = movies.map((movie) => <p key={movie.toString()}>{movie}</p>);
  return (
    <div>
        <Navbar />
        <h1>Predictions</h1>
        <br />
        <h2><Movies movie={movie_name}/></h2>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Predict
```

But I want this to be such that if the user hasn't submitted the form, then it navigates to `/apology` route, and if the FLASK API GET request returns an empty object, even then it navigates to `/apology` route. How do I do this? I understand this is conditional routing of some sort, but I havent been able to quite achieve where I should do this. Here `<Movies />` is simply a component that helps in showing the movie names

Comment: Are you really asking how to redirect to `"/apology"` from the `Predict` component on `"/predict"` if the user directly navigated there instead of submitting the form from that component rendering `Form`?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes... I'm not really all that familiar with hooks as fetch as of yet so I'm having trouble with conditional routing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a data to the `state` prop of the `location` object.

```
fetch('/predict', {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify(movie_submit)
}).then(() => {
  (navigate('/predict', { state: { wasFetched: true } }));
})
```

then in your `Predict` Component:

```
const { state } = useLocation();
const { wasFetched } = state;
useEffect(() => {
  if (wasFetched) {
    // user submited the form 
  } else {
    // user hasn't submited the form
  }
}, [wasFetched]);
```

Comment: ```const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('/predict', { state: { wasFetched: true } });
```
I assume I have to use this in the Form.jsx?

Comment: @Techie5879 yes, in: `.then(() => {
      (navigate("/predict"));
    })`, i will edit my anwser

Comment: @Techie5879 anwser edited

Comment: ```useEffect(() => {
  if (wasFetched) {
    // user submited the form 
  } else {
    // user hasn't submited the form
  }
}, []);
```
I assume in the if and else statements too I have to use navigate again? So For Predict too I need to import useNavigate and set a state and then navigate?

Comment: Also, this gives me an error React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'wasFetched'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Comment: @Techie5879 for the error, i forgot to add wasFetched to the hook dependency, updated the anwser. As for the first question, i really don't understand what you are asking, but if wasFetched is `true`, you do what you were doing in `useEffect`, if wasFetched is `false`, you navigate to the /apology route just like you said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248600/discussion-between-ricardo-dias-morais-and-techie5879).